# Format String to required format

Tags: java, string, eclipse, groovy, formatting

I have a string like this

```
String s = "[![(ASK,NO)|(ASK,YES)]&[[(TIME,A)&(TIME,B)]&![JAZ,A]]";
```

I want to format this to the below format.

```
(ASK != "No" || ASK != "Yes") && (TIME == "A" && TIME == "B") && (JAZ != "A")
```

There can be variations to the above format with the number of inner conditions and operators. Any suggestions on how to implement this in Java so that the formatting happens dynamically.

```
String s = "[![(ASK,NO)|(ASK,YES)]&[[(TIME,A)&(TIME,B)]&![JAZ,A]]";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
    int innerCount = 1;
    System.out.println(m.group(1));

    if(m.group(1).contains("(") && m.group(1).contains(")")) {
        Matcher mx = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(m.group(1));
        sb.append("(");

        while (mx.find()) {
            if(innerCount>1) {
                if(m.group(1).charAt((m.group(1).indexOf(")")+1))=='&') 
                    sb.append("&&");
                else
                    sb.append("||");
        }
                    
        String[] splitString = mx.group(1).split(",");
        sb.append("request.feature.");
        sb.append(splitString[0]);

        if(m.group(1).contains("!")) 
            sb.append("!=");
        else
            sb.append("==");

        sb.append("\"");
        sb.append(splitString[1]);
        sb.append("\"");

        innerCount++;
                
        sb.append(")");
    }
}
else
{
    sb.append("(");
    String[] splitString = m.group(1).split(",");
    sb.append("request.feature.");
    sb.append(splitString[0]);

    if(m.group(1).contains("!")) 
        sb.append("!=");
    else
        sb.append("==");

    sb.append("\"");
    sb.append(splitString[1]);
    sb.append("\"");
    sb.append(")");
}
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

The above code is what i have so far. I want the output to be like
(ASK != "No" || ASK != "Yes") && (TIME == "A" && TIME == "B") && (JAZ != "A")

I am stuck in figuring out how to handle the logical operators.

Comment: What problem exactly are you having doing this? Please read [ask].

Comment: Edited with more details.

Comment: what `groovy` tag is doing here if you are looking for java code?

Comment: I will recommend using a stack to solve this problem. Here link to the issue it's not the same but will be helpful. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/

Comment: "There can be variations to the above format with the number of inner conditions and operators" - Do any of the operators contain multiple characters and can an operator contain any of these characters (`(),[]`)?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - Possibly yes. I am trying a approach with Stack as suggested above. I am open to other approaches too.